# how can i convert datetime exactly to sql server datetime using linq

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2012

I have two fields in Model class

```
public DateTime START_DATE { get; set; }
public DateTime END_DATE { get; set; }
```

and a Class

```
string format = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss";
string startdate = timesheetModel.START_DATE.ToString(format, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
string enddate = timesheetModel.END_DATE.ToString(format, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);


var weekid = from data in db.WEEK_CALENDER
             where data.WEEK_START_DT ==Convert.ToDateTime(startdate) && data.WEEK_END_DT == Convert.ToDateTime(enddate)
             select data.ID;
```

But Getting Error Convert.ToDateTimes is not possible in linq
and Also in Sql Server as format like

```
2014-03-03 00:00:00.000
```

I Have tried in different ways, but i think it needs exact same format of sql server format.
and Tried in that format also , but not getting.
pls help me anyone.

Comment: Why are you converting all your `DateTime` instances into strings> LINQ to Entities understands the `DateTime` type.

Comment: Beacuse results are coming as null if i use same model types, because in sql server format 2014-03-03 00:00:00.000, but linq to entites taking as 03/03/2014 and i tried as converting format to 2014-03-03 00.00.00 but not getting..

Comment: @Sanjay MsSql will take both formats.  If you just try using the `START_DATE` & `END_DATE` does EF/MsSql throw a error?

Comment: No, but getting Empty Result, and i have tried with exact same value as in sql server, it is getting, but applying same value or converting is not accepting.@Justin

Comment: @Sanjay The format is an artefact of converting to a `string`. The internal format of `DateTime` is completely independent of any format.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert your datetime to string, this can only cause trouble

```
public DateTime START_DATE { get; set; }
public DateTime END_DATE { get; set; }

var weekid = from data in db.WEEK_CALENDER
where data.WEEK_START_DT == START_DATE && data.WEEK_END_DT == END_DATE
select data.ID;
```

Unless you are managing different type of calendar, weeks don't overlap and they all contain 7 days, so you should only need to check the WEEK_START_DT (or only WEEK_END_DT) and you will only get 1 week, so you could do this instead :

```
var weekid = db.WEEK_CALENDER.Single(data => data.WEEK_START_DT == START_DATE).ID;
```

An other idea, your method receives a single date, and if returns the weekId which contains this date, it doesn't have to be the specific start of the week, it could be any date.  This won't work of course if you are managing different type of weeks in your table.

```
var weekid = db.WEEK_CALENDER.Single(data => 
       data.WEEK_START_DT <= A_DATE 
    && data.WEEK_END_DT   >= A_DATE
).ID;
```